# (discord.js v12) Is it possible to send an embed with a message?

Tags: discord.js

The code is a temporary fix where it's broken into two messages:
https://sourceb.in/c34440e6bd

I have also attempted this `` updateChannel.send(`\|\|${updatePing}\|\|\n\n${updateEmbed}`) `` and `` updateChannel.send(`\|\|${updatePing}\|\|` + updateEmbed) ``

Both result in this:

```
||<@&724764442214268939>||
[Object object]
```

Is there a solution or do I have to keep it separate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
updateChannel.send(updatePing, updateEmbed)
```